# converting two lights from two switches to two lights from one switch

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have a double gang box with two switches that run different lights, from the same incoming cable (power through the switch first).  Therefore, I have one "incoming cable" and two "outgoing cables", one running to each light fixture.  I would like to make it so both lights operate off one switch, doing away with the other switch.  I want to make sure it is OK to run a pigtail hot wire off the switch and connect to the two hots of the cables running to the lights, while connecting all three neutrals together.  Is this the correct way to wire this situation?  Thanks for any advice/assistance.

Comment: Presumably the neutrals are already all connected together and pushed into the back of the box.  There would be no reason to disturb them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is acceptable. Don't forget the grounds, too.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, you can do as you describe

Having two switched-hot wires spliced to the same pigtail off the switch is fine here; you'll simply need to get a cover plate that has one gang set up for a toggle switch and the other gang set up for a blank, and make sure the always-hot lands on the other switch terminal, with no extra pigtails or the like.  Make sure all the neutrals are kept together with each other, and likewise with the grounds, too.